# How to find the distribution of star ratings to the business in the following cities? (SQLITE)

Tags: sqlite, distributed-availability-groups, sqlite-3.33

```
select stars
from business
where city = 'Avon';
```

Data:

```
+-------+
| stars |
+-------+
|   2.5 |
|   4.0 |
|   5.0 |
|   3.5 |
|   1.5 |
|   3.5 |
|   4.5 |
|   3.5 |
|   2.5 |
|   4.0 |
+-------+
```

Result Needed:

```
Star     Rating Count
0           0
1           0
1.5         1
2           0
2.5         2
3           0
3.5         3
4           2
4.5         1
5           1
```

Comment: What about 0.5 stars? The query you need is actually quite easy: you just need to `count()` the rows grouping by `star`. Then left outer join that to a list of all the possible stars so you can get the zeros.

Answer (score 1):

The basis of the query is

```
SELECT stars, COUNT(*) ratio_count FROM business
 where city = 'Avon'   GROUP BY  "stars"
```

Which would give amount üf the stars, but as you also wanted the number 0 for all the stars not given, you must add also a table that contains all stars

> ```
> CREATE TABLE business
>     ("stars" INTEGER,
>     "city" varchar(10))
> ;
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO business
>     ("stars","city")
> VALUES
>     (2.5,'Avon')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO business
>     ("stars","city")
> VALUES
>     (4.0,'Avon')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO business
>     ("stars","city")
> VALUES
>     (5.0,'Avon')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO business
>     ("stars","city")
> VALUES
>     (3.5,'Avon')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO business
>     ("stars","city")
> VALUES
>     (1.5,'Avon')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO business
>     ("stars","city")
> VALUES
>     (3.5,'Avon')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO business
>     ("stars","city")
> VALUES
>     (4.5,'Avon')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO business
>     ("stars","city")
> VALUES
>     (3.5,'Avon')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO business
>     ("stars","city")
> VALUES
>     (2.5,'Avon')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO business
>     ("stars","city")
> VALUES
>     (4.0,'Avon')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>   t2."stars",  IFNULL(ratio_count,0) ratio_count
> FROM 
>   (select a as stars from
> (select 0.5 as a union select 1 union select 1.5 
> union select 2 union select 2.5  union select 3 
> union select 3.5 union select 4 union select 4.5 union select 5 )) t2 
> LEFT JOIN (SELECT stars, COUNT(*) ratio_count FROM business
> where city = 'Avon'   GROUP BY  "stars") t1 
> ON t2.stars = t1.stars
> ```

> ```
> stars | ratio_count
> ----: | ----------:
>   0.5 |           0
>     1 |           0
>   1.5 |           1
>     2 |           0
>   2.5 |           2
>     3 |           0
>   3.5 |           3
>     4 |           2
>   4.5 |           1
>     5 |           1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=8639f0a97c1464048593ebb8ba2d9edc)*